# Permanently disable schema in MS Web Developer 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsd

I have an .xsd schema in SVN and it's copy in %VsInstallDir%\xml\Schemas.
Schema folders in Web Developer settings include only %VsInstallDir%\xml\Schemas.
Option "automatically download schemas and DTDs" is disabled.

**Problem:** When I edit copy of .xsd from SVN, Web Developer automatically starts to use it and immediately clutters error log with conflict warnings (The global element 'NAMESPACE:value' has already been declared).
I can disable usage of xsd from SVN in the schema management window (XML -> Schemas...), but if i load another XML with relevant namespace in Web Developer, that schema becomes enabled again. And conflict warnings appear again...

**Question:** Is there any way to permanently prohibit Web Developer to load shemas from selected path?
I've tried to look into catalog.xml, but apparently it allows only to add path, not to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem this way:

1. Removed scheme from %VsInstallDir%\xml\Schemas
2. Added path to copy of schema from SVN to catalog.xml

I know, it seems obvious, but I didn't realize this solution for quite a time :)